# Clustering with Adobe software

Tags: cluster

i find myself working a lot with Premiere Pro, After Effect, Encoder and Encore, and i was thinking if there is a way to share the computational load to some computer on the same lan to speed up all the computing those software have to do all the time. There is any way to share the load on more than one computer?

Answer (score 2):

[DrQueue](http://www.drqueue.org/cwebsite/about_drqueue.php), which is open source software, can do that for After Effect, I used it a few years ago to distribute Maya renders, worked like a charm.